# Xcode Beta 6.2 does not start App Watch extension

Tags: xcode, ios8, watchkit

My watchkit app can't run on simulator.

After I choose the xxx Watch App scheme, and click Run,

It display "Running xxx on iPhone 6", but never go to the second step of 
"Running xxx WatchKit Extension", so Watch application never displayed.

I following Apple's standard steps of creating a simple demo application. Apple's demo app can't be started either. Anything I did wrong?

Comment: This kind of question is probably better suited towards the Apple developer forums: http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: 1. Select iPhone 5 or higher (iPhone 4s now showing watch emulator).
2. Go to Hardware > External Displays > Select one of Watch external displays.

Comment: From the 8.2 beta Release Notes:  When you choose Build and Run it doesn't launch the Watch window.  Workaround: Open the Watch window under Hardware > External Displays and then choose Build and Run again.

Comment: Having same problem. Developer forum says nothing on this issue.

Comment: Same here.. I re-asked it as the dev forum is not useful so far...

Comment: You should try on the iPhone 5S simulator.